# Pandas reading file with inconsistent tabs in header

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm reading a data set where columns we're added to the historical files and I want to read the files consistently. The problem is the older files is missing a column don't have the correct number of tabs in the header which leads the first column being read as the index.

The `bad.csv`

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
6   2   3           
5   2   4
```

A `good.csv` that loads correctly

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
6   2   3           
5   2   4
```

I'm reading the csvs file `df = pd.read_csv('bad.csv', sep='\t')`

I can detect if a file is bad by looking at the index, how can i correct the bad files so that it loads without Col1 being part of the index? I tried `df.shift(1, axis=1)` but this doesn't include the index, which I can set after shifting but I'm worried this might create more issues. ex:

```
df = df.shift(1,axis=1)
df.Col1 = df.index
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: According to the docs, read_csv with index_col=False is to force not to use the first column as the index

Comment: @Ze'evBen-Tsvi make an answer that's much cleaner than what I came up with and works for both cases!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> Note: index_col=False can be used to force pandas to not use the first
> column as the index, e.g. when you have a malformed file with
> delimiters at the end of each line.

So I make sure that every line is ended with \t

bad.csv:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
2   4   6   8   10
3   5   8   10  13
4   8   12  16  20  24
15  13  11  9   7   5
1   1   2   3   5   8
```

Then:

```
df = pd.read_csv('bad.csv', sep='\t', index_col=False)
```

**outcome**

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  Unnamed: 5
0     2     4     6     8    10         NaN
1     3     5     8    10    13         NaN
2     4     8    12    16    20        24.0
3    15    13    11     9     7         5.0
4     1     1     2     3     5         8.0
```